# Пишу сайт на Express и Handlebars. Почему не подключаются стили?

Tags: css, handlebars

Всем привет. Делаю вывод списка постов с ссылкой в каждом "Открыть пост". Открываю пост, страница грузится, но стили не подключаются. То есть по id все данные выводятся, но стили не подключаются...

```js
const {Router} = require('express')
const Publication = require('../models/publication')
const router = Router()

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const publications = await Publication.getAll()
    res.render('blog', {
        title: 'Блог',
        isBlog: true,
        publications
    })
})


router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const publication = await Publication.getById(req.params.id)
    res.render('publication', {
        title: 'Пост',
        isBlog: true,
        publication
    })
}) 


module.exports = router
```

вот страница с постом, стили почему-то не подключаются. В чем проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать каталог, где хранятся эти файлы - статическим, то есть.. Перед всеми вашими роутами нужно добавить строку:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: она есть!......

Comment: const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const mainRoutes = require('./routes/main')
const blogRoutes = require('./routes/blog')
const feedbackRoutes = require('./routes/feedback')
const messageRoutes = require('./routes/message')

const app = express()

const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: 'hbs'
})

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', 'pages')

Comment: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use('/', mainRoutes)
app.use('/blog', blogRoutes)
app.use('/feedback', feedbackRoutes)
app.use('/message', messageRoutes)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`)
})

Comment: вот содержимое index.js

Comment: Вы можете это добавить в свой вопрос? Так не удобно читать. А ткак же, мне кажется эти строки должны быть ПЕРЕД роутами, а у вас получается после них.